# How to toggle my div content independently using a single jquery script

Tags: jquery

Please, some contents in my div were hidden using the script below, with a read more button to display the full contents of each div. The problem is that when i click on the read more button, it displays the contents of all divs with "class abt". Is there a way to maneuver this, so i dont have to create multiple class and multiple script to match each of the classes??

Below is my script:

$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".abt").hide();
            $(".toggle").click(function(){
        $(".abt").toggle();
        $(".toggle").hide();

            });
        });

Below is my html content

```
   <div>lets make the <span class="abt">World a better place     </span>         <a style="font-weight:bold;" class="toggle">Read more</a>  </div>
```

Hello world Hello stackoverflow      Read more  

This is the lifeI want to live    Read more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below jquery

```
$('a.toggle').click(function(){
    var hiddenElem = $(this).parent().find('.abt');
  $(hiddenElem).toggle();
});
```

Refer my link : https://jsfiddle.net/fwec0cca/3/

Comment: I copied and pasted the code same way it is here, added css to hide the class abt. When i click on read more, nothing happens.. Pls, is there anything i must have done wrong as to why it is not responding?

Comment: Ok.. i figured it out.. I inserted the code at the top. i later moved it to the bottom page, and it worked fine.. Thank you very much, i appreciate